# Laravel Ardent many-to-many relationship is throwing error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1, ardent

I have an [Ardent](https://github.com/laravel-ardent/ardent) v3.3.0  model like this:

```
class Company extends Ardent
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'address'
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        'name'    => 'required',
        'address' => 'string'
    ];

    public function workers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Worker')->withPivot('worker_type');
    }
}
```

Another model that goes something like this:

```
class Worker extends Ardent
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        'name'    => 'required',
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company')->withPivot('worker_type');
    }

}
```

In my controller I'm calling a save method like this:

```
$worker = New Worker;
$worker->name = "Jane Smith";

$company = Company::find($id);
$company->workers()->save($worker, ['worker_type' => 'contractor'];
```

According to Laravel's and Ardent's docs I'm correctly forming my relationships but Ardent throws an error: `ErrorException in Ardent.php line 821: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

[image: Ardent error message]

What's causing this error? Is it a bug in my code or Ardent's?

Note: I'm using Ardent version 3.3.0, the issue disappears when I roll back to version 3.0.0

Comment: Please post the version of Ardent you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the rules for one or more of your models that extend Ardent.

```
class Whatever extends \LaravelArdent\Ardent\Ardent {
   public static $rules = [];
}
```

Line [821](https://github.com/laravel-ardent/ardent/blob/master/src/Ardent/Ardent.php#L821) shows that we're looking for an array called `$ruleset` that we can't find.

Comment: I have not added `$rules` to the question above but I do have them in my model file. I will update the question to reflect this.